# Pull some configuration variables from the DB to set dynamically in Rails environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-4.2

**Is it possible to set some configuration variables in `production.rb` dynamically using values from the database?**

I'm building a multi-tenant app and each tenant has some environment specific information that needs to be set dynamically.

For example:

```
// production.rb
config.action_mailer.default_url_options  = { :host => current_tenant.domain }
```

The `current_tenant` is a helper method is defined in `ApplicationHelper` so can't be accessed in `production.rb`

Here is `current_tenant`:

```
// application_helper.rb
def current_tenant
  @current_tenant ||= Tenant.find_by(domain: Apartment::Tenant.current)
end
```

If not, is it possible to dynamically create `secrets.yml` using DB data? Since then I would be able to use `ENV` in `production.rb`

Comment: How do you access to your current tenant? Could you do a middleware?

Comment: @Mkou Added to question. How can I do this in a middleware?

Comment: Can you try setting url host in mailer it self assume mailer class  is UserMailer
`UserMailer.default_url_options[:host] = 'domain'`

Comment: The mailer is just one example, there are other config variables that need dynamic data as well from the database.

Comment: Could you give us other examples?

Comment: One more thing can you just add a `before_filter set_tenant_config` in ApplicationController and do all your config in that method

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this instead:
Create a helper method for your emails:

```
def build_tenant_url(route_name, *args)
  opts = args.extract_options!
  opts.merge!(host: @tenant ? @tenant.domain : your_domain)
  #Here you can merge other options if you need to pass a token etc
  Rails.application.routes_url_helpers.send(:"#{route_name}_url", *args, opts)
end
```

In your mailer, define the @tenant

Then in your email view use it

```
= link_to 'Edit', build_tenant_url(:edit_tenant, @tenant)
```

Comment: The mailer is just one example, there are other config variables that need dynamic data as well from the database.

Comment: Could you give us other examples?

Comment: Another example is initializers. The Devise gem's initializer would need api_keys for Facebook and Google (which are specific to each tenant).

Comment: Another example for `production.rb` is the Paperclip gem and it's global configuration with Amazon S3 api keys (which are again specific to each tenant).

Comment: As the configuration is ran once when the app is created, you can't configure your app in more than one way. You will have to solve one problem at a time

Answer (score 0):

This setup runs when the app starts up, so if you want an option to be driven by some variable, that variable will need to be available to the Ruby code that runs at startup.  There's various ways this could be done

- the script (or whatever) which starts your rails server passes through a parameter
- a value is written into a text file by some other process and read out again by the startup script
- same again but with an environment variable

For example, if you were giving each tenant (group of users) their own subdomain on your app, then the subdomain name could be used as a key for the startup code to read the database and pull out some details for that tenant.  This subdomain would then be passed through to the app when you spin it up.

EDIT - having said all this, i'm not sure if it's necessary for you to change the startup config at all.  Can't you just look up the appropriate domain name whenever you send an email, rather than changing the default set in the config?